# jQuery .html() and .attr() not working after .get() call

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to get jQuery to change the html of a div and src of an img after receiving data from a .get ajax call. Here is the code:

```
function setUpUser(method) {
    $.get("scripts/loggedIn.php", {
        method: method
    })
        .done(function(data) {
    $('#loginForm').css("display", "none");
    $('.account').css("display", "block");
    $('#userName').html(data.userName);
    $('#displayPic').attr("src", data.imagepath);
    $('.mask').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('.loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
    }, "json");
}
```

I did a console.log() to check if data.userName and data.imagepath are correct and they were. But when the call happens, all the code executes but the div and img remain empty. Any jQuery gurus want to help?

EDIT:

Fixed! I removed the "json" from the end of the call and used JSON.parse(data) instead. This is the fixed code:

```
function setUpUser(method) {
    $.get("scripts/loggedIn.php", {
        method: method
    })
        .done(function(data) {
    var info = JSON.parse(data);
    var imagepath = info.imagepath;
    var name = info.userName;
    console.log(imagepath);
    $('#loginForm').css("display", "none");
    $('.account').css("display", "block");
    $('#userName').text(name);
    $('#displayPic').attr("src", imagepath);
    $('.mask').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('.loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
}
```

It seems that the "json" was converting the "data" AFTER the text and attr needed to be set. I think.

Comment: You might want to use `.text()` on the `#userName` bit, unless `data.userName` includes the tags.

Comment: It might be that you have the wrong ids. For instance, if you are using ASP.NET and a master page, then the IDs are getting prefixes. Otherwise, maybe you already have a src attribute and you are adding a second src?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#userName').html(data.userName);` --> try using text()

`$('#displayPic').attr('src', data.imagepath);`  --> imagepath may need formatting relative to your JS file.

Comment: I just tried using .text(), still doesn't work. Also, the img src, I checked using firebug, the src was empty after the call, so I assume reformatting would be another issue, the main problem here is that jQuery just isn't putting the info in. Do I need to parse the json before putting the data in?

Comment: Are you sure your get is working? It seems like your data.userName and data.imagepath do not contain anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try using...

```
$('#userName').text(data.userName);
$('#displayPic').prop('src', data.imagepath);
```